# Show that the set of one-to-one holomorphic maps $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{a,b,c\} \to \Bbb{C}\setminus\{a,b,c\}$ forms a finite group.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\Omega = \mathbb{C}\setminus\{a, b, c\}$ be the complement of three distinct points in the complex plane. Show that the set of one-to-one holomorphic maps $f : \Omega \to \Omega$ forms a finite group. Is the order of this group independent of the choice $\{a, b, c\}$?

By Casorati-Weierstrass, none of the points can be essential singularities for $f$. However, it is possible that at least one of the points is a pole, for example $f : \mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1, 0, 1\} \to \mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1, 0, 1\}$, $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$.   For this choice of points, we also have $z \mapsto z$, $z \mapsto -z$, and $z \mapsto -\frac{1}{z}$, so $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 \leq \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1, 0, 1\})$. Furthermore, for any $a, b, c$ on a straight line, we can conjugate by a rotation, a translation, and a rescaling to get a corresponding subgroup. If I had to guess, the group will depend on whether or not $a, b, c$ are collinear.

Any hints on how to proceed would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps first decide whether a one-to-one holomorphic map that fixes each of $a,b,c$ must be the identity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First normalise the situation. Since the structure of the automorphism group is preserved under biholomorphisms, we can map $\Omega$ to $\Omega' = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1,c'\}$ per $z\mapsto \frac{z-a}{b-a}$.

Now consider the situation from the viewpoint of the Riemann sphere, $\Omega' = \widehat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \{0,1,c',\infty\}$.

Each of the four points is a removable singularity of $f\in \operatorname{Aut}(\Omega')$ when that is considered as a holomorphic map to the sphere, so $f$ extends to an automorphism of the sphere. Hence

$$\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega') = \left\{f\in \operatorname{Aut}(\widehat{\mathbb{C}}) : f(\{0,1,c',\infty\}) = \{0,1,c',\infty\}\right\},$$

and we see that $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega')$ can be viewed as a subgroup of $S_4$.

Now investigate what restrictions the location of $c'$ imposes on the permutations of the four points that arise from automorphisms of the sphere.

---

We always have the four automorphisms

$$T_1 \colon z \mapsto z;\quad T_2\colon z \mapsto \frac{c'}{z};\quad T_3\colon z\mapsto \frac{z-c'}{z-1};\quad T_4\colon z \mapsto c'\frac{z-1}{z-c'}$$

of $\Omega'$. The three non-identity automorphisms among them swap the four points in pairs, and each point in $\{0,1,c',\infty\}$ is mapped to $c'$ by one of these four.

Thus, if $f$ is any automorphism of $\Omega'$, $T_i\circ f$ is an automorphism of $\Omega'$ that leaves $c'$ fixed for exactly one $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$. So it suffices to see which Möbius transformations permuting $\{0,1,\infty\}$ have $c'$ as a fixed point. Ignoring the identity, we have

- $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$, which swaps $0$ and $\infty$ and has the fixed points $1$ and $-1$, so is an automorphism of $\Omega'$ if and only if $c' = -1$;
- $z \mapsto 1-z$, which swaps $0$ and $1$ and has the fixed points $\infty$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, so is an automorphism of $\Omega'$ if and only if $c' = \frac{1}{2}$;
- $z\mapsto \frac{z}{z-1}$, which swaps $1$ and $\infty$ and has the fixed points $0$ and $2$, so is an automorphism of $\Omega'$ if and only if $c' = 2$;
- $z\mapsto \frac{1}{1-z}$, which cyclically permutes $0 \mapsto 1 \mapsto \infty \mapsto 0$, and its inverse $z \mapsto 1 - \frac{1}{z}$, which have the fixed points $e^{\pm \pi i/3}$, so are automorphisms of $\Omega'$ if and only if $c' = e^{\pi i/3}$ or $c' = e^{-\pi i/3}$.

We see that generically, $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega')$ is a Klein four-group, but for some special situations, the automorphism group is larger.

If $c' \in \left\{ -1, \frac{1}{2}, 2\right\}$, there is one nontrivial automorphism of $\Omega'$ having $c'$ as a fixed point [an involution], and $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega')$ is (isomorphic to) the dihedral group ($D_4$ or $D_8$, depending on the used nomenclature) of the rigid motions of a square.

If $c' = e^{\pm \pi i/3}$ (then the three points $0,1,c'$ form an equilateral triangle), there is a nontrivial automorphism of period $3$ of $\Omega'$ having $c'$ as a fixed point, and then $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega')$ is (isomorphic to) the alternating group $A_4$ of even permutations of $\{0,1,c',\infty\}$.

Comment: The automorphisms of the Reimann sphere are Möbius transformations which preserve the cross ratio of any four points, in particular $\{0, 1, c', \infty\}$. The kernel of the action on $\{0, 1, c', \infty\}$ by $S_4$ is the Klein four group, so $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega') \leq \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. I imagine the value of $c'$ will effect which subgroup it is. Am I on the right track?

Comment: We need not have $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega') \leq \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. If for example $c' = 2$, then $z \mapsto \frac{2}{2-z}$ is a cycle of order $4$, $0 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto \infty \mapsto 0$. But yes, the value of $c'$ affects the subgroup.

Comment: I understand why $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega')$ is not necessarily a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. However, I don't know how to determine which elements of $S_4$ correspond to Möbius transformations. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio#Six_cross-ratios), there are six possible values of the cross ratio under permutations, and as Möbius transformations preserve the cross ratio, any permutation which leads to a different value of the cross ratio can't be induced by a Möbius transformation. But even if there is a permutation which doesn't change the . . .

Comment: . . . cross ratio, it's not clear to me that there is a Möbius transformation which realises this permutation.

Comment: The brute-force way: Take three points in $\{0,1,c',\infty\}$. Map them to $0,1,\infty$ in that order. See where the transformation maps the fourth point. If it doesn't map it to $c'$, the transformation doesn't belong to $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega')$, if it does, it belongs. Slightly less brute-forcish, you look at the cross-ratios. $\operatorname{CR}(c',0,1,\infty) = c'$ (or, if you use the other widespread convention for the cross-ratio, $\operatorname{CR}(c',1,0,\infty) = c'$).

Comment: You can express the possible values for the cross-ratios of the permutations in terms of $c'$, and those where the cross-ratio is $c'$ belong to $\operatorname{Aut}(\Omega')$, the others not.

Comment: Using the less brute-forcish way, if you find a permutation which gives the same cross ratio, how do you know that there is indeed a Möbius transformation which realises this permutation?

Comment: The cross-ratio _is_ a Möbius transformation. Depending on the convention used $$\operatorname{CR}(z,a,b,c) = \frac{z-a}{z-c}\frac{b-c}{b-a}$$ is the Möbius transformation sending $(a,b,c)$ to $(0,1,\infty)$ (with appropriate interpretation as a limit resulting in the removal of factors containing $\infty$ if one of $a,b,c$ is $\infty$), or $$\operatorname{CR}(z,a,b,c) = \frac{z-b}{z-c}\frac{a-c}{a-b}$$ is the Möbius transformation sending $(a,b,c)$ to $(1,0,\infty)$ (with the same proviso about one of $a,b,c$ being $\infty$).